# App Closes after getting redirected to an Activity When back pressed on click of push notification

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

I am in big trouble and the scenario is that I have an app so when i open it up the the back stack of activities is like activity A is splash and then move to B then C and then D. So when i press back button the order of activites launch is D-C-B-A. But when a push notification is hit and after clicking on it it open Activity D. Now When I Press Back button the app closes instead the behaviour of app should be that it should redirected back to the activity (Let us say activity B )which is running at the time when notification is not clicked. 
Thanks in advance and I would appreciate for the suggestions.

Update Here is my Message Handler

```
 @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String bundledata = data.getString("data");
        String message=data.getString("message");
        sendNotification(message,bundledata);
        NOTIFICATION_ID++;
    }

    private void sendNotification(String message,String bundledata) {

        intialization();
        setNotification(message,bundledata);

    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    private void setNotification(String message,String bundledata)
    {

        NotificationManager  mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        stackBuilder.addParentStack(GcmNotificationRedirect.class);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, GcmNotificationRedirect.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("pushMessage", message);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("bundleData",bundledata);
        notificationIntent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);


        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent( NOTIFICATION_ID,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
                );


       // NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle notiStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(message))
                        .setContentText(message)
                        .setNumber(pushNumber);


            mBuilder.setColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.theme_color));
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon);
            mBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), getNotificationIcon()));


        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
        Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    }
```

The activity which redirect message to different activity

```
public class GcmNotificationRedirect extends Activity {

    String pushMessage;
    String bundleData;
    Push_Notification_Pojo pojo;
    public static final String PRODUCT_PAGE="PRODUCT_PAGE";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pushRedirect();

    }

    private void pushRedirect()
    {
        pushMessage = getIntent().getStringExtra("pushMessage");
        bundleData = getIntent().getStringExtra("bundleData");

/*
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(GcmNotificationRedirect.this,NavigationController.class);
        intent1.putExtra("pushMessage", pushMessage);
        intent1.putExtra("bundleData",bundleData);
        startActivity(intent1);*/

        parsePushNotifiactionJson(pushMessage,bundleData);
        finish();

    }

    private void parsePushNotifiactionJson(String pushMessage, String bundleJSONData){
        Intent pushNotiInetent = null;

        if(pushMessage!=null && bundleJSONData!=null) {
            try {

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(bundleJSONData);

                if (jsonObject.getString("type").equals(PRODUCT_PAGE)) {

                    pojo = new Push_Notification_Pojo(jsonObject.getString("productId"), jsonObject.getString("type"),pushMessage);
                    pushNotiInetent = new Intent(this, ProductDetail.class);
                    pushNotiInetent.putExtra("push_notification_pojo", pojo);
                    startActivity(pushNotiInetent);
                }

                else
                {
                    pojo = new Push_Notification_Pojo(jsonObject.getString("promotionId"), jsonObject.getString("type"), pushMessage, true);

                    if(pojo!=null)
                    {
                        NavigationController.menuRequired=NavigationController.PERMOTIONAL_OFFERS;
                        pushNotiInetent = new Intent(this, NavigationController.class);
                        pushNotiInetent.putExtra("pushMessage", pushMessage);
                        pushNotiInetent.putExtra("bundleData",bundleData);
                        startActivity(pushNotiInetent);
                    }
                }

               // pushNotiInetent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: please post relevant part of code and logcat output with error stacktrace...

Comment: There is no error. I will paste the code shortly

Comment: ok , then I think the code with your notification and Activity D is important....

Comment: GcmNotificationRedirect activity is only for parsing the json and redirecting app to other activites. So here when the notification is clicked the GcmNotificationRedirect will redirect to particular activity. So from this activity when i press back button to go  to last page visible but the app closes.

Comment: you called `finish()` in `pushRedirect()` method whose job is to kill an activity.

Comment: I tried removing finish() and then went back but it open the blank activity and then the app closes but i was unable to redirect where i was in the app(lets say email page).